# Azure Wrangling data flow doesn't appearing

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to use the `Wrangling data flow` in `Azure Data Factory v2`, but this data flow doesn't appearing for me.

I followed this tutorial [Prepare data with wrangling data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-data-flow-tutorial)

We have this image to create the wrangler:
[image]

But, in my subscription these options doesn't appearing for me.
[image]

I searched in many websites, tutorials and I didn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure data wrangling in data flow is actually moved below as "**Power Query**".

for more details watch the official docs video:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/wrangling-overview#use-cases

Answer (score 0):

If you have already create the Wrangling data flow, I think you can select it.

In your screenshot, it seems you dont select the 'Use existing data flow':

[image]